# Trying to upgrade to latest version of SalesforceSDK

Tags: mobilesdk

I have an iPad application that is using Salesforce SDK 6.2.0, which I am trying to upgrade to the latest version of SDK. I ran the pod install, but I’m getting the following error:
'SalesforceSDKCommon/SFLogger.h' file not found in @interface SFSDKMobileSyncLogger : SFLogger class

#import <SalesforceSDKCommon/SFLogger.h>

Any insight on how to complete the SDK upgrade?